# Configure Apache to run a nancy website

Tags: apache, razor, nancy, xamarin-studio, razorengine

I am creating a website/webapi using Nancy with the Razor engine.  Has anyone been able to configure and host such a site using Apache (latest version)?  I see some posts talking about configuring FastCGI which requires some specific code in the app startup.  I am using the latest Xamarin studio on a mac to develop this site.

Comment: I can help with nginx :) not apache tho :( sorry.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, but the only requirement is that it be hosted from a non-microsoft OS.  I see nginx has been out a while, still a viable option for the long term?

Comment: @MarkErickson Hi, did you solve your problem? let me know how....

Comment: I have not solved this as of yet.  Unfortunately due to time constraints we had to go out the door with just IIS hosting.